# pgrouting tsp (travelling salesman problem) performance

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, pgrouting, postgis-2.0, travelling-salesman

I currently use a web API to solve TSP tasks. However my provider limits the query to a maximum of 150 stops. I therefore consider to host my own routing service based on OSM data and pgrouting. My top priority is performance and I was wondering if anybody has experience with the performance of the pgr_tsp function?
I don't care about exact stats or system specs. All I want is a ballpark figure in order to see if pgrouting is an option at all.

E.g. Can I calculate TSP for 1000+ stops and is this a matter of seconds or hours?

Comment: To give you an idea (not pgrouting based but our RW Net 4 software): With 1000 stops we recommend appr. 50 sec of calculation to get a decent solution. With multiple threads or if you accept a not so good solution, it can be faster. In any case you will also need a cost-matrix between the 1000 stops and here calculation time depend a lot upon distance between stops and level of details in the network.

Comment: @UffeKousgaard Thanks for the reply. Calculating the actual network distance matrix for 1000 stops (i.e. ~1.000.000 routes), seems impractical. I read that using euclidean distance is often sufficient to get a near optimal solution. How do you get your distance matrix? Do you actually calculate all shortest paths?

Comment: Yes, using euclidean distance is a joke IMHO, if you are going to use the result for anything serious. Calculations are done as 1000 one-to-many, rather than 1,000,000 one-to-one.

Comment: Real cities has oneway streets, rivers, railways and many other obstacles, which prevent straight lines when moving from one stop to another.

Comment: @UffeKousgaard Yes, I read that in the postgreSQL pgrouting docs and that's how they implemented their tsp algorithms default behaviour. However, I also realized that it does not really work for small areas. I.e. stops are distributed on a street level rather than spread across multiple cities. The euclidean only seems to work well for long distance TSP. I assume this is because the street network becomes sufficiently dense when you zoom out and the euclidean distance converges with the actual driving distance.

Comment: Correct, and with 1000 stops I bet you are planning for newspaper distribution or similar short distances between stops within a city.

Comment: @UffeKousgaard yes you are correct :) It's actually a route optimization for garbage collection trucks. I'll try to figure out how to calculate the distance matrix with pgrouting and will post my results, if it works in a reasonable amount of time (which I almost doubt)

Comment: checkout https://github.com/woodbri/vehicle-routing-problems this has a complete trash collection solving solution. We also link directly to OSRM to compute the routes. The pgrouting TSP solver takes a distance matrix, and using simulated annealing and should give you results pretty quickly although I have not timed it for 1000+ sized problems. I have also implemented psql wrappers to OSRM https://github.com/woodbri/osrm-tools but this code is pretty dated. We used a shared memory connection in the vehicle-routing-problems code to interface to OSRM which is much faster them the http connection

Comment: (continued) that I used in the osrm-tools. Talking to OSRM will be faster then  pgrouting, but trash containers do not move that often so computing a distance matrix once and then updating it occasionally should work. pgrouting has many new function for many to many and one to many solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Complementing, previous answer..
montevideo-release-v4
is the latest branch.
There is a lot of clean up that needs to be done as everything we coded is still there even if its not used.

Answer (score 0):

The authors of "Fast data-oriented microaggregation algorithm for large numerical datasets" [1] proposed a TSP solution for millions of cities in Euclidean space. Their solution is fast enough for your application and is based on Clark-Wright heuristic.

[1] http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0950705114001956